# Workflow history retention duration for a SPD workflow?

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-designer

With Visual Studio Workflow, I use to add

`<AutoCleanUpDays>9999</AutoCleanupDays>`

in order to keep the history of workflow for a longer time.

How can I do the same for a wf built with SPD 2010 ?

I tried to manually update the myworkflow.xoml.wfconfig.xml, but it breaks the workflow.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that in SP 2010, there is not a time limit (was 60 days) like there automatically was in SP 2007. You should be able to set a retention policy for the History list just like any other list. Add /lists/workflow%20history to the URL for the pertinent site and that should get you to the correct list(s). If you cannot find your specific History lists, see - http://www.sharepoint911.com/blogs/laura/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=119 as there might be an issue regarding that.

rlr